# What theories/sub-fields have developed out of ethnography?

Tags: social-sciences

Ethnography & ethnomethodology, as both being around for quite a while there must be theories/sub-fields which have developed out of these.

Coming from an interactionist point of view, I'm aware of social network theory (Milroy & Milroy, 1978) & Conversation Analysis, the sub field.

However, I'm looking for more theories/sub-fields to really drive my point about it being a useful method historically, and still is useful.

This is primarily from social sciences, such as anthropology, sociology, linguistics etc. etc.

Any suggestions/guidance are greatly appreciated.

Comment: *History and Theory in Antrhropology* by Alan Bernard (Cambr.UP,2000) contains a valuable discussion of terms, traditions and languages, e.g. what the German called Ethnologie and what did the French understand; it might be useful.